# Cooking IN CO2 gas?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, home-experiment, theoretical-chemistry, food-chemistry

Quick theoretical question:

What if I replaced water with dry ice in my pressure cooker?  Assuming I used a calculated amount to prevent an explosion...

Would It be able to cook?

Would it dehydrate the food to any degree?

Would it penetrate into the center?

Comment: If you put the dry ice on the bottom and let the gas flow over the food it could freeze dry the food to an extent, but not cook it.

Comment: **SAFETY - Trying this would be a very bad idea.** The metal vent in the pressure cooker would get cold enough to freeze water. A plug of ice could block the vent and cause a dangerous pressure build up -- think explosion! There is a safety release typically on a pressure cooker, but it is uncertain if an ice build up could occur simultaneously on that too. Why fool around with something that could explode?!? There are safer and quicker ways to dehydrate food.

Comment: In short, your pressure cooker will (almost) become an equivalent of the Boston Marathon bomb.

Comment: Of course I would not try this.  The idea is not to freeze dry the food nor to dehydrate it any more than deep frying would. 

My question remains, maybe I needed to be more specific as to say that I would turn the machine on.  Could the heat from the machine heat the sublimated CO2 fast enough to melt the potential icing problem in the vent and subsequently cook the food?

Comment: The idea is that I could cook food under pressure with a gas, since a pressure cooker will not build pressure with just air.  

Essentially an air fryer but under pressure.

Comment: Why CO2? Just don't put any water in the pressure cooker and you would get the same effect. Which won't, most likely, be good. The reason why a pressure cooker works is that it allows water to boil at a significantly higher temperature which is why it cooks food faster. With no water the hot gas will generate the same pressure but there will be no liquid to warm up and heat the food: you'd basically be pressure frying which has no advantage over normal frying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, this would not work because of the way pressure cookers cook**

The reason why pressure cookers work to cook food faster is that water boils at a higher temperature when under pressure. This extra temperature cooks food faster that water boiling at 100 C. The pressure is merely a means to ensure that higher temperature.

Typical pressure cookers regulate the pressure to about twice normal atmospheric pressure. This increases the boiling point of water to about 120 C. The cooking is also enhanced by the fact that, when pressurized, most of the gas inside will be water vapour which has a much higher specific heat capacity than most other gases so cooking uncovered food more effectively than most alternative vapours at the same temperature.

Not adding water defeats this mechanism. Heating a pressure cooker *without* water will generate the pressure (even if you don't add CO2, the air will heat quickly and generate pressure). But that pressure can't go above the regulated level (unless you block the release valve, which just creates a bomb, not a cooking vessel). And there will be no fluid in the cooker to spread the heat around and it is likely that you would just see uncontrolled temperatures in the parts of the food in contact with the surfaces with no way to transfer that heat to the rest of the food. So you will, basically, be frying your food and gaining no benefit from the pressure while being unable to see what is happening (which is not usually a good way to fry things).

Using solid CO2 won't make much difference except to make the process take longer because part of the vessel starts really cold.